# Add extra layers to pre-trained model at input in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science

I have `facet` model (ckpt and meta files) which takes input of size `(batch_size,160,160,3)` and gives output of size `(batch_size,128)`.

My input is a k-dimensional vector and I have a pre-processing function(consists of some convolution and pooling layers) which takes my input and gives `(batch_size,160,160,3)` output.

How do I add this function to trained model in tensorflow and save the model?

I'm new to TF.